# How do I find particular Javascript within my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebug

The problem is that I have a huge Javascript code, it's broken down into many files.
And I can't seem to find where a particular javascript code is .

How would you go about finding if you were in my place?

I have the firebug lite installed but no clue how to use it. Thank you.

P.S. I'm not able to comment on SO for some reason. Sorry.

Comment: `grep` is handy. Also, most IDEs/advanced programming editors will have a "find in files/project".

Comment: Do you know the exact function name?

Comment: No it's not a function. It's a jquery thing.

Comment: It was the CSS causing the hover action ! When did CSS get so much power !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a text editor with a ***Find In Files*** option like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Most IDEs would also provide this search option.

[image: Find in Files]

Comment: This will not help if the script is loaded from an external server

Comment: @Simeon Firebug won't help either if we're using server-side JavaScript. As for the two down votes, please explain why. :)

Comment: There is no `SSJS` or `serverside-javascript` tag attached to the question. However, the Firebug tag is attached.

Comment: @Simeon Firebug helps me debug. When programming, I don't save files through firebug. Those are two different contexts and I simply provided an answer that is less dependent on a firebug and more integrated toward producing code. Why not downvote `grep` answers because they're not related to firebug? I don't believe that answers should be dependent wholly on tags when there viable alternatives available; otherwise, why bother having multiple answers on SO in the first place?

Comment: I downvoted your answer because of two things: 1) It is useless when you don't have the files accessible locally. Which is a  common use case for web developers. 2) The question was tagged `firebug` and can thus be answered in a more useful way than described in 1). If you disagree with that, then so be it. But I am using my right to downvote an SO answer that I find insufficient.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) link, specifically these headlines:

> **Find scripts easily**
>
> Many web applications are comprised of
> quite a number of files, and finding
> the one you want to debug can be a
> chore. Firebug's script file chooser
> sorts and organizes files into very
> clean list that will help you find any
> file in a snap.
>
> **Go directly to line 108, do not pass go**
>
> Often times you want to jump directly
> to a specific line of your script.
> Doing this couldn't be easier, just
> type the line number into the quick
> search box, preceded by the pound
> sign, as seen in the screen shot on
> the right.

Find scripts: [image] Search scripts: [image]

Comment: great answer - great software

Answer (score 0):

you can search for function names in the firebug search box, which will also search across multiple js files

just open firebug and on the right hand side should be a searchbox.  there are even check boxes for searching multiple files, case insensitivity and the use of regex if you feel ambitious.

Comment: hmm I thought "firebug search box" was sufficient, but @Simeon has a nice picture of it

Comment: It was the CSS causing the hover action ! When did CSS get so much power !

Answer (score 0):

there's always: `grep -r 'function myHardtoFindFunction(' src/`

on a unix system or another system with GNU utilities.